# Mailing labels for Viet Nam do not render the Vietnamese alphabet correctly

Tags: address-labels

```
Mr. Nguyen Khach Son
29 Che Lan Vien, #3
?à N?ng, 60
VIET NAM
```

The name of the city is spelled Đà Nẵng in Vietnamese. When the pdf file is created, it is not using the proper encoding.

Comment: Is this similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/special-characters-become-question-marks-in-pdf-printing?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes. That didn't come up for me. Will this be patched permanently?

Comment: The solution offered in the post is pretty complex. This should be fixed in the  CiviCRM distribution

Comment: I found that mailing label is not using dompdf. It uses tcpdf instead. Please refer to [link] (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/additional-fonts-for-tcpdf)